# Why tesorflow changes predictions when not changing the code?

Tags: tensorflow

I made a very simple `xor` predicting DNN. It goes as follows.

```
p = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_keys(column_name="p", keys=["0","1"])
q = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_keys(column_name="q", keys=["0","1"])
p_emb = tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(sparse_id_column=p, dimension=1)
q_emb = tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(sparse_id_column=q, dimension=1)

input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({
        "p": np.array(["0","0","1","1"]),
        "q": np.array(["0","1","0","1"])},
    np.array([0,1,1,0]),
    batch_size=4,
    num_epochs=1000)

estimator = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=[p_emb, q_emb],
    hidden_units=[3],
    optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(
        learning_rate=0.05
    ))

estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=5000)

print(list(estimator.predict({
        "p": np.array(["0","0","1","1"]),
        "q": np.array(["0","1","0","1"])})))
```

Sometimes (more than average) it correctly predicts `[0,1,1,0]` but other times it predicts very wrongly.

It could be because the choice it mades at first, which after making it the weights go in one direction of training which is not the correct one, but how can I be almost certain (95% up) that the predicted value will be the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a high- level approach of Tensorflow, so I'd expect quite some work is done under the hood. One of that is usually initializing the weights with some **random** values.

Thus- every new **training** will produce a different starting point and thus achieve different learning results. Usually this process is monitored using *validation*- and *test*- sets.

The optimizer you are using (Stochastic Gradient Descent) will usually only find a *local minimum* (except your problem fulfills certain properties [*convexity*]). So it is crucial what initialization the optimization is started with.

However- a trained NN - independent of how good or bad it is designed or trained - should yield the very same result for the very same input as long as it was not trained further or changed in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `GradientDescentOptimizer` depends on many factors such as the initial weight, the training examples in each batch and so on. So on different runs the weight may be initialized differently, and other factors may be different as well, which may result in different classification. You cannot be certain with specific percentage (95% up). You can do some things (for example, increase the number of training examples, if you can) that may improve your classification accuracy, but nothing guarantees you mathematically that you will get an accuracy of 95% or above.

Comment: what about adagrad?

Comment: So a solution could be to export the weights at a certain point, when you know the answer is good enough?

Comment: You will have similar issues with adagram and other optimizers as well. You can read here about the behavior of different optimizers  http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/

Comment: Regarding your second comment. Saving such weights not necessarily guarantees good accuracy, as you may have high training score but low test score. So you need to make sure that your test score is high as well. You can also try to use cross validation http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79490/neural-network-with-and-without-cross-validation